# Finding corrupted images

Tags: photo-management

Are there any good Ubuntu/Debian/Linux-based tools for identifying corrupted jpeg images in a collection of tens of thousands?  I know that there are a few in there, but I can't bring myself to view them all manually, even at the thumbnail level.

Comment: Corrupted in what way?

Answer (score 6):

It might not be perfect, but you could use [`feh -p`](https://man.finalrewind.org/1/feh/) and examine the error messages generated.

To list all the unloadable images in /opt/images and below

```
feh -ur /opt/images
```

> `-u`, `--unloadable` Don't display images.  Just print out their names if imlib2 can NOT successfully load them.  Returns false if at least one image was loadable.
>
> `-r`, `--recursive` Recursively expand any directories in the commandline arguments to the content of those directories, all the way down to the bottom level.

Comment: From `info feh` ... `feh --unloadables -r /opt/images` *Weed  out  (list)  all  the  unloadable  images in /opt/images and below.*

Comment: Actually, it's `feh --unloadable -r /opt/images` or `feh -ur /opt/images`.

Comment: Missed a description, or a link: http://man.finalrewind.org/1/feh/ "feh is an X11 image viewer aimed mostly at console users".